# What hisorical time period does Kuhn's "pre-paradigm state" correspond?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method, kuhn

In Thomas Kuhn's analysis of scientific development, in *The Structure of Scientific Revolutions*, the "pre-paradigm state" is a condition in which all members of the scientific community practice science but in which their gross product scarcely resembles science at all, because of the proliferation of competing schools.

Does the "pre-paradigm state" correspond to a specific historical time period?
If yes, is it correct to say it corresponds to the period before XVII century, that's to say before modern science?

Comment: It depends on the "science" : physics, chemistry, etc. We may say that e.g. sociology is still in the "pre-paradigm state".

Comment: For physics (aka : natural philosophy) the "official" *paradigm* has been Newton's [Principia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica), published 1687.